# How to obtain three arrays containing three objects or less?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to obtain three arrays containing three objects or less. I have a class named Product and an array who have 9 products or less downloaded form Firebase, so I want to generate three arrays, each one will have three different products in order. This is what I have:

```
var products = [Product]()
products = [product1, product2, product3, product4, product5, product6, product7, product8, product9]
```

And this is what I want to obtain:

```
array1 = [product1, product2, product3]
array2 = [product4, product5, product6]
array3 = [product7, product8, product9]
```

In some cases the array named product will have a number of products less than 9 so I have to create those arrays automatically with 3 or less products.
I'm doing this because my code have to generate an array that has three arrays inside, each one with three products or less to show in a collection view inside a tableview `[[Product]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice an array by using the [] operator with a range.  Note that this returns a view into the original array, so if you want a copy you pass the slice to Array() to create a new copy:

```
let numbers:[Int] = stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 1).map{$0}
print(numbers.count)
let first = Array(numbers[0...2])
let second = Array(numbers[3...5])
let third = Array(numbers[6...8])
print(first, second, third)
```

To convert an array of arbitrary length into a number of arrays with 3 elements or less:

```
let numbers:[Int] = stride(from: 1, to: 14, by: 1).map{$0}
var bins: [[Int]] = []
for index in stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: 3) {
    let endIndex = min(index + 2, numbers.count - 1)
    bins.append(Array(numbers[index...endIndex]))
}
print(bins)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo expects the extra variables to contain empty arrays when there are fewer than 6 or 3 products.

this should do it:

```
    let productsBy3 = (0..<3).map{ i in products.indices.filter{$0/3==i}.map{products[$0]}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it Works!!